# Is it possible to rewrite routes in Laravel 5, in routes file

Tags: routes, url-rewriting, laravel-5

Is it possible to perform a URL rewrite but in Laravel 5's routes.php file rather than my .htaccess file? I know this is easy with a redirect but I would preferably avoid doing that so to keep the short url in the address bar.

Say I have the url 'http://website.com/store/clothing/shites/cool-shirt' that would use the route:

```
Route::get('store/{category}/{subcategory}/{product}', [
    'uses'=>'StoreController@getProduct'
]);
```

I would like to create a shortcut URL 'http://website.com/cool-shirt' that would fetch the full url from a database table and then call the correct route and parameters (without a redirect).

```
Route::get('{slug}', function($slug){

    $shortcut = \App\Shortcut::whereSlug($slug)->first();

    // I'm making the execute_route() function up here
    return execute_route($shortcut->full_url);

})
```

Basically calling a route within a route.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you want to achieve, instead of trying to call another route inside the present one , I recommend that you use only one route for the requests, handle the database query in a controller and show and return a view based on the current slug or throw a 404.

Like so:

```
Route::get('/{slug?}',array(
    'uses' => 'ShortcutController@getSlug',
    'as'   => 'shortcut.getSlug'
));



<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use \View;
use App\Shortcut;


class ShortcutController extends Controller {


    public function getSlug($slug=null){
        if(!$shortcut = Shortcut::whereSlug($slug)->first()) abort(404);
        return view('slug')
            ->with('shortcut',         $shortcut);

    }

}
```

**NB:** The route above should be the last listing on your routes.php else some other routes might be matched